# Modem 3G - Two different IPs

Tags: networking, ip, port, 3g, modem

I just saw something I never have seen before. 
I got a new SIM card from Nextel (communication company). I tried to use it on a 3G modem E3131, where I had a successful case before with VIVO (another communication company). Now it is different, instead to have only an external IP, I'm getting two different IPs.

For example:

When I go to some service like whatismyip.com, I see an IP 200.xxx.xxx.xxx, but when I check it out on ipconfig /all, I see another IP 10.xxx.xxx.xxx.

My problem is I can't connect to my app from another computer because there's no port redirection to internal IP. I must connect to some specific ports.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get an e3131 Quick Start modem?

Comment: Hi @S List

I tried in both, an E303C with quick start and an E3131 without quick start. At the first case, it gives me two IPs: 2xx.xxx.xxx.xxx (external) and a 192.168.1.100 (internal). On E3131, it gives me also two different IPs: 2xx.xxx.xxx.xxx and 10.xxx.xxx.xxx. When I change the broadband company (other SIM card), it gives me only external IP and everything works fine. Brazilian companies buy these modems from HUAWEI, and no one is able to give me an acceptable support because even they don't know how it works.

Comment: I haven't tested the E3131 but here is a suggestion: Maybe, all such modems are quickstart, and whether QS is activated is controlled by some configuration, eg. a registry key.  The 2 IP addresses are easy to explain; the QS device makes its own IP connection, so it gets its own IP address, and that's the address seen by whatismyip.  The Windows IP stack gets a separate IP address.  Try looking in the registry (if you're confident with that) to see if you can switch QS off.  Or did you get any dashboard with your old SIM? maybe install that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your point, but I'm not sure if it will work. I'm using the same dialer that I've created on Windows for both connections (with VIVO and Nextel). I will try to find the registry.

Comment: Only make changes in the registry if you are confident what you are doing! (sorry, I don't know how experienced you are).  I think the Windows dialer doesn't make a difference.  The QS stuff is on the stick, and you need to find how to deactivate it.  QS will automatically make a connection, independently of the Windows dialer if it's activated.

Comment: Hi S List. I already tried to access the switching page, install additional drivers and connect via terminal to switch it for modem mode, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: I tried based on this:
http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=68136